# jquery extend of prototype

Tags: javascript, function, extend

i have some javascript code that i use in my html pages, the .js file looks like this:

```
(
function(exports){
  var cubism = exports.cubism = {version: "1.3.0"};
  var cubism_id = 0;
  function cubism_identity(d) { return d; }
  ...
}
)(this);
```

i want to add some new functionality to the base library, so i do the following (sorry in coffeescript):

```
jQuery.extend cubism.context.prototype,
   "horizon": () ->
       metric = cubism_identity
```

the problem is when i run the code i get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cubism_identity is not defined
```

how can i access the function `cubism_identity()` in my extended prototype?

Comment: Is that `cubism_identity` available outside that module at all? Please show us the code where it's exported. If not, you'll have to edit the base library file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is available within the scope it is defined and not at a higher level scope unless it is specifically assigned as a property on a higher level object.

With the way you've written your code, `cubism_identity()` is a function that is only visible inside the scope of your `function(exports){` function body.  If you want it available outside that scope, then you will have to either define it at a higher scope where you can then use it or you will have to assign it as a property of some higher level object such as `window` or your own namespace object.

For example, you could move it to the global scope:

```
function cubism_identity(d) { return d; }

(
function(exports){
  var cubism = exports.cubism = {version: "1.3.0"};
  var cubism_id = 0;
  ...
}
)(this);
```

Though, it is generally better to put it on a global namespace object so you don't add more things to the global scope than needed.

Or, conversely, you could define the function that uses it inside the `function(exports)` body so it can use it right where you originally had it.